# LWC Datepicker in modal not displaying correctly

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, inputdate

I have a requirement wherein I used

`<lightning-input type="date" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>`

for adding a datepicker in a modal pop up. But, the date-picker doesn't display correctly and is cut off from the browser.

[image]

So, is there a way so that I can have date-picker expand in the upward direction and not in the downward direction? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @rohit-maharashi,   Is this a standard modal or a custom LWC component?

Answer (score 2):

Please update your lightning modal content styles like below code.

```
<div class="slds-modal__content" style="overflow: visible !important;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use inline styling: `style="bottom: 100%"`

The code will look like following:

```
 <lightning-input type="date" variant="label-hidden" style="bottom: 100%"></lightning-input>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't help my cause

Comment: I have this lightning-input inside a modal so can you suggest something else.

Answer (score 1):

I've set the `overflow: hidden;` on the input element, and it solved the issue.

before:
[image]

after:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use some custom LWC modal component, you could replace the standard classes used with custom ones to remove 50% width constraint and some other which prevents date pickers from working correctly.

If you the following line in your modal html file:

```
<div class="slds-modal__container">
```

replace it with

```
<div class="container">
```

and add some styles from `slds-modal__container` to your custom css file

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    transition: transform var(--lwc-durationQuickly,0.1s) linear,opacity var(--lwc-durationQuickly,0.1s) linear;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 var(--lwc-varSpacingXLarge, spacingXLarge);
    height: 100%;
    padding: var(--lwc-squareIconLargeBoundary,3rem) 0;
    border-radius: var(--lwc-borderRadiusMedium,0.25rem);
}
```

If you using your LWC inside the standard Quick Action modal, there is no other workaround that redirect to custom component